# Is a primary key necessary for greenplum database?

Tags: greenplum

We know greenplum is a MPP data wirehouse, we will import data from mysql into it every day, the primary key may conflict from different source. I am designing the schema, I am not sure:

Is primary key required for each table?

From offical docs, the primary key is used for partition by default, but I can specify another key to partition, is there any other reason that I have to set a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a primary key is not needed in Greenplum.  It will actually slow down your loading performance, take up storage space, and likely not be used for any queries.

The distribution key is often times set to be the logical primary key of a table but without an actual primary key created.  The distribution key should be a high cardinality column like the primary key, which helps distribute the data evenly across the segments. 
 And you can specify another key for the distribution key too.

Lastly, I wouldn't call this a way to "partition" the data because partitioning is something else in Greenplum.  Partitioning is akin to Oracle or SQL Server partitioning with the query optimizer eliminating partitions based on the conditions (where month = 1) in the query.